# Mysql event doesn't run

Tags: mysql, mysql-event

I am trying to set an event in my Mysql database that will run every minute to update a table. This is my code I put to run:

```
UPDATE credit SET daily ='1000' WHERE Id=1
```

This is the message I get after I set the event

```
CREATE DEFINER=`xxx_knxxc`@`localhost` EVENT `zero_column`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE STARTS '2018-07-07 14:49:00'
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE
DO UPDATE credit SET daily ='1000' WHERE Id=1
```

Comment: "This is the message I get after I set the event" Your message is the SQL code what is the real message/error?

Comment: There is no error message, the message I get after is what I see after I set the event. I put my code in the definition field and the rest parameters i select from dropdown lists

Comment: Do you see it if you do `SHOW EVENTS`?

Comment: Did you enable the event scheduler? Try `SELECT @@event_scheduler;` to see if it's enabled.